# Schema.org newsArticle > entry-summary?

Tags: html, schema.org, microformats

I'm using Schema.org newsArticle object definition to markup news items.
With Microformats > atom markup one would use the entry-summary class.

What do you think the Schema.org equivalent is [`<tagname itemprop="about">`](http://schema.org/about)?

Answer (score 2):

The schema.org/NewsArticle property "about" should be a schema.org/Thing instance.

If you're asking what property of schema.org/NewsArticle you should map the  Microformats > atom "entry-summary" class then I would suggest the "description" property of schema.org/NewsArticle, which is defined as "A short description of the [news article]."

Comment: That's indeed what i'm asking. Makes sense. Thanks for your input.